# Underline covers text in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to create an attributed string but the underline covers my text instead of appearing behind it:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I'm using the following code:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10.0

let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleThick.rawValue,
                  NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.red,
                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Story", attributes: attributes)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

To give more context:

I'm displaying the attributed string on a UILabel placed in a .xib file:

```
view.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

The label has the following font:
**System Bold 32.0**

I'm running the code on iPhone 6 - iOS 10.3 simulator.

EDIT 2:

I should have mentioned that the label may, at some point, contain more than one line of text. That's why the numberOfLines is set to 0.

EDIT 3:
If anybody encounters this problem -- it seems that there is a lot of difference in how underline is drawn on iOS 9 vs 10 as well as UILabel vs UITextView. I've ended up having to draw the underline myself by subclassing NSLayoutManager.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. On my machine, the underline is nicely separated from the text, and does not intersect the descender of the "y". https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXs4R.png Please show more of your code, to make this reproducible. How are you displaying this attributed string? What font are you using? And so on.

Comment: Same here, I also can't replicate your problem in my machine. It is showing nicely separated from the text. @Grzegorz Aperliński

Comment: (Also I may mention that your code did not compile on my machine. It is necessary to declare `attributes` explicitly as being of type `[String:Any]`.)

Comment: Added more details in the main entry.

Comment: See my revised answer. You cannot set the `font` in Interface Builder but everything else in the `attributedText`; you must include the font specification _in_ your `attributedString`. As my revised answer shows, when you do that, all is well.

Comment: Put the same attributed string in a UITextField and the underline looks OK now. Thanks again for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is such problem as you have described. It shows up when you use multiline `UILabel`, so not only setting `numberOfLines` to 0, but type more than 1 line in it.

**Example**

```
let selectedStringAttributes: [String: Any]
    = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28),
       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green,
       NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
       NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 500, height: 100))
label.numberOfLines = 0

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "String to test underline", attributes: selectedStringAttributes)
```

And everything will look pretty good.

But if you want to use such text:

```
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "String to\ntest underline", attributes: selectedStringAttributes)
```

or label's width is too short, than:

[image: Not so good]

So the reason for such behaviour is of course [bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/31174934) in `NSAttributedString`. As it mentioned in radar there is a **workaround**

You should add this attribute to your `NSAttributedString`

```
NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 0
```

And magic will happen.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've actually implemented custom drawing using a subclass of NSLayoutManager. Hopefully, this issue will be resolved in the future.

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, showing your attributed string in a black-backgrounded UILabel, it makes a quite nice-looking display:

[image]

The red thick underline is nicely separated from the text, and is interrupted to allow the descender of the "y" to pass through it.

**NOTE** You cannot combine the `font` of the UILabel (set in Interface Builder) with its `attributedText`. You must set the *entire* label's text formatting in the `attributedText`. So, my code looks like this:

```
    let attributes : [String:Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                      NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleThick.rawValue,
                      NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.red,
                      NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Story", attributes: attributes)
    lab.backgroundColor = .black
    lab.attributedText = attributedString
```

(You will notice that I removed your stipulation of the paragraph line spacing; there is only one line, so this stipulation adds nothing. However, I get the same result even if I restore it.)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I've noticed little difference, at least in rendering, between the font weight set in code and IB. I've finally discovered the source of the problem (and edited the original entry) – the problem occurs if you set the number of lines to 0. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I was changing this but didn't think it was relevant...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using NSAttributedString you can draw border below the label with x space using this.

```
let space:CGFloat = 10

let border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (label?.frame.size.height)! + space, width: (label?.frame.size.width)!, height: 1)
label?.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've considered doing this but there may be more than one line of text so this doesn't cut it for me.

Answer (score 2):

So this is my solution to this issue.
I think it is "cleaner" and easier.
Post me if you dont understand :)

```
class BottomLineTextField: UITextField {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setBottomBorder()
    }

    func setBottomBorder() {            
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bottomBorder = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        hasError = false
        bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(bottomBorder)

        bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true // Set underline height
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is ok as long as there is only one line of text.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzAperliński , you right.
I did that just for one line

Answer (score 0):

I know its late reply but after hours search, found a fix as below

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func withUnderlineSpacing(spacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length))
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length))
        return attributedString
    }
}
```