# Add Space between Text and Underline in Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift

I am struggling with spacing issue between underline and attributed Text.
As below screen shot

[image]

I tried to add HTML string with below tutorial https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-display-html-in-uilabel-and-uitextview/ but could not change space between text and underline.

I also tried with [Underline covers text in NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785665/underline-covers-text-in-nsattributedstring) but could not achieve.

Please suggest how we can achieve this.

Comment: I'd tend to say you need to play with CoreText, or if you use a `UITextView`, with `NSLayoutManager` (if I remember correctly), as Underline rendering is limited to the provided effects (with `NSUnderlineStyle`).

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Is this for UILabel? UITextField? UITextView? Are you using `AttributedString` or `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Underline covers text in NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785665/underline-covers-text-in-nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got a solution after hours search on NSAttributed string (posting if any developer faces similar issue)

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func withUnderlineSpacing(spacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length))
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length))
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your answer on two questions, why not close this questions as a duplicate of the other?